# Raspberry PI USB to RS232 adapter Receiving Only Ctrl Chars

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I'm using a USB to RS232 cable for get communication with a pure rs232 device.
With pyserial lib a got this code running in loopback tx -> rx cable pins.

Setting the port:

```
def __init__ (self, baudrate,timeout,parity,stopbits,bytesize):
    try:
        #self.s = serial.Serial(port="'/dev/ttyUSB0'",baudrate=baudrate,timeout=timeout,parity=parity,stopbits=stopbits,bytesize=bytesize)
        #self.s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
        self.s=serial.Serial(
            "/dev/ttyUSB0",
            baudrate=9600,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
            writeTimeout = 0,
            timeout = 10,
            rtscts=False,
            dsrdtr=False,
            xonxoff=False)
    except:
        print ("Can't open Serial Port")
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

Writing and reading from it:

```
def write(self,data):
    if self.s.isOpen():
        try:
            self.s.write(data)      
            self.s.flush()
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            print "Error on writing"
    else:
        print "Port is closed"

def read(self):
    receivedData=[]
    if self.s.isOpen():
        try:
            while self.s.inWaiting()> 0:
                receivedData.append(self.s.read(1))
            return receivedData

        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout) 
            print "Error on Reading"
    else:
        print "Port is closed"
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

I sent 'Carlos'.

And received ['\x03', '\x01', '\x12', '\x0c', '\x0f', '\x13']

It is hex representation of ^C^a^r^l^o^s

I need to know why it is converting chars to control chars?

Comment: You also connected the ground wires between the devices? :)

Comment: Thank you for reply! Yes the ground is connected between the devices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of attempts without any idea about how fix this problem, I bought new cable USB to RS232, it is based on Prolific PL2303 Chipset and it is working properly right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you would expect if the sending end is using only 5 bits.

First check the settings on the sending device.
If possible, verify the bits are being send with an oscilloscope or logic analyser.
Perhaps the dongle is broken.
Maybe some part of the system has a poor power supply and the final 3 bits are not being detected properly.

Comment: Thank you for reply and sorry for my english.. I dont have a oscilloscope for a deep analyse, but I sent a lot of message and  all my tests the number of bytes are right. But it seems using the Control Characters instead the printables ones. For example a sent  'A' and get '\x01' no printable char (^A) I also test the same code using pure tx/rx on raspiberry gpio and its works properly.

Comment: Does it work if you used the same code and dongle on your PC? For 9600 baud, you could look at one of the PC oscilloscope projects that uses your soundcard.

Comment: I did not  test this code on PC yet but I will,I just tested the cable loop back on Windows, after install its drivers. I found there is a compatibility problem with HL-340 Chipset used into this cable adapter. Although I can access  /dev/ttyUSB0 normally, so I'm still looking for a solution and I'm going to try analyse  it with some pc oscilloscope project as you suggested.